# MFP 7.1 - Unauthorized error if App is kept in background for a while

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When App loads everything works fine but if App is kept in background for a while like 15 to 20 minutes And then if any adapter call is made We start getting Unauthorized error and communication between server and client stops until app is killed and reloaded.

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
POST http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url 500 (Internal Server Error)
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _submitLoginFormCallback(): response: {"request":{"options":{"method":"post","asynchronous":true,"contentType":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","encoding":"UTF-8","parameters":{"username":"BKAC7759","password":"TODAY01"},"evalJSON":true,"evalJS":true,"requestHeaders":{"x-wl-app-version":"1.0","X-WL-ClientId":"txi6uhiRuF","X-WL-S-ClientId":"txi6uhiRuF","X-WL-Session":"a024e87e-4f12-1ec2-4d5c-d8a2b82fd896"}},"transport":{},"url":"/MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url","method":"post","parameters":{"username":"BKAC7759","password":"TODAY01"},"trackingId":"2e3aebe5-3ba1-2ac2-332d-37d6f33b868f","networkMetadata":{"$path":"http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url","$category":"network","$trackingid":"2e3aebe5-3ba1-2ac2-332d-37d6f33b868f","$outboundTimestamp":1461690389486,"$inboundTimestamp":1461690389720,"$bytesReceived":0,"$roundTripTime":234,"$responseCode":500},"body":"username=BKAC7759&password=TODAY01","_complete":true},"transport":{},"readyState":4,"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error","responseText":"Error 500: FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url [project MyProject]\r\n","headerJSON":null,"responseXML":null,"responseJSON":null}
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"…}
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
Request [http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login]
[MY.controllers.login] _loginComplete(): login step completed: undefined
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _handleChallenge(): Handle Challenge : realm:  MYRealm
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _handleChallenge(): Challenge Required.
[MY.controllers.login] _loginRequired(): login required: {"authStatus":"required"}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
XHR finished loading: GET "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?response…F%2Fmfpredirecturi&scope=MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.3972540041119985".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
response [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat] success: 
Heartbeat sent successfully
[MY.controllers.login] buttonClicked(): Enter
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] submitLogin(): realm, username  MYRealm BKAC7759
Request [login]
[MY.controllers.login] buttonClicked(): Exit
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _submitLoginFormCallback(): response: {"request":{"options":{"method":"post","asynchronous":true,"contentType":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","encoding":"UTF-8","parameters":{"username":"BKAC7759","password":"TODAY01"},"evalJSON":true,"evalJS":true,"requestHeaders":{"x-wl-app-version":"1.0","X-WL-ClientId":"txi6uhiRuF","X-WL-S-ClientId":"txi6uhiRuF","X-WL-Session":"a024e87e-4f12-1ec2-4d5c-d8a2b82fd896"}},"transport":{},"url":"/MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url","method":"post","parameters":{"username":"BKAC7759","password":"TODAY01"},"trackingId":"4866d09a-e7f5-8026-63dc-cb33c8aa2ac4","networkMetadata":{"$path":"http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url","$category":"network","$trackingid":"4866d09a-e7f5-8026-63dc-cb33c8aa2ac4","$outboundTimestamp":1461690398949,"$inboundTimestamp":1461690401013,"$bytesReceived":25,"$roundTripTime":2064,"$responseCode":200},"body":"username=BKAC7759&password=TODAY01","_complete":true},"transport":{},"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"OK","responseText":"{\"authStatus\":\"complete\"}","headerJSON":null,"responseXML":null,"responseJSON":{"authStatus":"complete"}}
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _handleChallenge(): Handle Challenge : realm:  MYRealm
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _handleChallenge(): Challenge Not Required
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
Request [http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login]
[MY.controllers.login] _loginComplete(): login step completed: undefined
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _handleChallenge(): Handle Challenge : realm:  MYRealm
[MY.controllers.login] _loginComplete(): login step completed: undefined
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/login".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
XHR finished loading: GET "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?response…F%2Fmfpredirecturi&scope=MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.6668569553490127".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 222, statusText: "Undefined"…}
response [http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization] success: 
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 222, statusText: "Undefined"…}
Request [http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/token]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/token".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
response [http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/token] success: {"scope":"MYRealm wl_antiXSRFRealm wl_anonymousUserRealm","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"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.eyJpbWYudXNlciI6eyJpZCI6IkJLQUM3NzU5IiwiYXV0aEJ5IjoiRENTU1JlYWxtIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6IntcImxvZ2luSWRlbnRpdHlcIjpcIntcXFwidXNlcm5hbWVcXFwiOlxcXCJCS0FDNzc1OVxcXCIsXFxcImxvZ2luU3RhdHVzXFxcIjpcXFwic3VjY2Vzc1xcXCIsXFxcImZpcnN0TmFtZVxcXCI6XFxcIkJST09LRSAgICAgICAgIFxcXCIsXFxcImxhc3ROYW1lXFxcIjpcXFwiS0FDRVZJQyAgICAgICAgICAgICBcXFwiLFxcXCJzdGF0dXNcXFwiOlxcXCJBY3RpdmVcXFwiLFxcXCJpcm5cXFwiOlxcXCI1MzQ0OTg0OVxcXCIsXFxcInVzZXJUeXBlXFxcIjpcXFwiQ29uc3RpdHVlbnRcXFwiLFxcXCJhbGxvd2VkUm9sZXNcXFwiOltcXFwiQ3VzdG"}
XHR finished loading: GET "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/SecurityAdapter/security/login".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "{'secretData':'1234567'}", invocationContext: null}
[MY.controllers.login] Login Completes Successfully
[MY.controllers.login] :loginIdentity: {"username":"BKAC7759","loginStatus":"success","firstName":"BROOKE         ","lastName":"KACEVIC             ","status":"Active","irn":"53449849","userType":"Constituent","allowedRoles":["Custodian","NonCustodian"],"userCases":[{"irn":771036557,"caseNumber":90018572,"firstName":"NOAH           ","lastName":"LANDI-RODRIGUEZ     ","role":"Custodian"},{"irn":52292240,"caseNumber":170022954,"firstName":"NOAH           ","lastName":"LANDI-RODRIGUEZ     ","role":"Custodian"},{"irn":53449831,"caseNumber":110022149,"firstName":"BELINDA        ","lastName":"KACEVIC             ","role":"NonCustodian"}]}
[MY.controllers.login] :UserInfoService: {"username":"BKAC7759","cplist":[{"irn":771036557,"caseNumber":90018572,"firstName":"NOAH           ","lastName":"LANDI-RODRIGUEZ     ","role":"Custodian"},{"irn":52292240,"caseNumber":170022954,"firstName":"NOAH           ","lastName":"LANDI-RODRIGUEZ     ","role":"Custodian"},{"irn":53449831,"caseNumber":110022149,"firstName":"BELINDA        ","lastName":"KACEVIC             ","role":"NonCustodian"}],"irn":"53449849","firstname":"BROOKE         ","lastname":"KACEVIC             ","loginstatus":"success","allowedroles":["Custodian","NonCustodian"],"usertype":"Constituent","status":true,"selectedcase":[],"limbo":false,"demographics":[]}
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/init]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/init".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
response [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/init] success: /*-secure-
{"userInfo":{"SubscribeServlet":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_directUpdateRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"send-message":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"get-subscriptions":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"send-bulk-messages":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":"3622e77a-b9f1-4fbe-8201-34bf2130d1dc","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"3622e77a-b9f1-4fbe-8201-34bf2130d1dc","deviceId":"3622e77a-b9f1-4fbe-8201-34bf2130d1dc"},"wl_authenticityRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"MYRealm":{"userId":"BKAC7759","attributes":{"loginIdentity":"{\"username\":\"BKAC7759\",\"loginStatus\":\"success\",\"firstName\":\"BROOKE         \",\"lastName\":\"KACEVIC             \",\"status\":\"Active\",\"irn\":\"53449849\",\"userType\":\"Constituent\",\"allowedRoles\":[\"Custodian\",\"NonCustodian\"],\"userCases\":[{\"irn\":771036557,\"caseNumber\":90018572,\"firstName\":\"NOAH           \",\"lastName\":\"LANDI-RODRIGUEZ     \",\"role\":\"Custodian\"},{\"irn\":52292240,\"caseNumber\":170022954,\"firstName\":\"NOAH           \",\"lastName\":\"LANDI-RODRIGUEZ     \",\"role\":\"Custodian\"},{\"irn\":53449831,\"caseNumber\":110022149,\"firstName\":\"BELINDA        \",\"lastName\":\"KACEVIC             \",\"role\":\"NonCustodian\"}]}"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":null,"deviceId":"BKAC7759"},"SampleAppRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"uu39jsbudjfiuttj6ohr2i7e1b","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"uu39jsbudjfiuttj6ohr2i7e1b","deviceId":"uu39jsbudjfiuttj6ohr2i7e1b"},"myserver":{"userId":"3622e77a-b9f1-4fbe-8201-34bf2130d1dc","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"3622e77a-b9f1-4fbe-8201-34bf2130d1dc","deviceId":"3622e77a-b9f1-4fbe-8201-34bf2130d1dc"}},"userPrefs":{},"gadgetProps":{"ENVIRONMENT":"common"}}*/
wlclient connect success
Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined at (compiled_code):3900
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/PaymentAdapter/payment/info/cp".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[]", responseJSON: Array[0], invocationContext: null}
resp: klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[]", responseJSON: Array[0], invocationContext: null}
[MY.controllers.paymenthistory] payment info cp on case change successful
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/CaseAdapter/case/info".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "{"funDesc":"Process used to close a case when chil…IGUEZ","children":{"name":["BRAYDEN KACEVIC"]}}]}", responseJSON: Object, invocationContext: null}
[MY.controllers.home] caseDetails Response{"funDesc":"Process used to close a case when children emancipate or other reasons exist. ","caseDetails":[{"_case":90018572,"statusCode":"Case Closure","statusDate":{"year":2012,"month":2,"day":3,"timezone":-2147483648,"hour":-2147483648,"minute":-2147483648,"second":-2147483648},"office":{"name":"LOOKOUT MOUNTAIN OFFICE","street1":"10056 N HWY 27","street2":"","street3":"","city":"ROCK SPRING","state":"GA","zip5":"30739","zip4":"","hours":"M-F 8:00 A.M. to 5:00 P.M.","fax":"7063750700","email":"ROCKSPRINGCSE@MY.GA.GOV                          "},"otherParent":"NOAH LANDI-RODRIGUEZ","children":{"name":["BRAYDEN KACEVIC"]}}]}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/CaseAdapter/case/info".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "{"funDesc":"Process of establishing paternity (leg…IGUEZ","children":{"name":["BRAYDEN KACEVIC"]}}]}", responseJSON: Object, invocationContext: null}
[MY.controllers.home] caseDetails Response{"funDesc":"Process of establishing paternity (legal fatherhood) and/or child support order.","caseDetails":[{"_case":170022954,"statusCode":"Establishment","statusDate":{"year":2013,"month":1,"day":8,"timezone":-2147483648,"hour":-2147483648,"minute":-2147483648,"second":-2147483648},"office":{"name":"LOOKOUT MOUNTAIN OFFICE","street1":"10056 N HWY 27","street2":"","street3":"","city":"ROCK SPRING","state":"GA","zip5":"30739","zip4":"","hours":"M-F 8:00 A.M. to 5:00 P.M.","fax":"7063750700","email":"ROCKSPRINGCSE@MY.GA.GOV                          "},"otherParent":"NOAH LANDI-RODRIGUEZ","children":{"name":["BRAYDEN KACEVIC"]}}]}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/PaymentAdapter/payment/info/cp".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[]", responseJSON: Array[0], invocationContext: null}
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "{"funDesc":"Process of establishing paternity (leg…IGUEZ","children":{"name":["BRAYDEN KACEVIC"]}}]}", responseJSON: Object, invocationContext: null}
[MY.controllers.home] caseDetails Response{"funDesc":"Process of establishing paternity (legal fatherhood) and/or child support order.","caseDetails":[{"_case":170022954,"statusCode":"Establishment","statusDate":{"year":2013,"month":1,"day":8,"timezone":-2147483648,"hour":-2147483648,"minute":-2147483648,"second":-2147483648},"office":{"name":"LOOKOUT MOUNTAIN OFFICE","street1":"10056 N HWY 27","street2":"","street3":"","city":"ROCK SPRING","state":"GA","zip5":"30739","zip4":"","hours":"M-F 8:00 A.M. to 5:00 P.M.","fax":"7063750700","email":"ROCKSPRINGCSE@MY.GA.GOV                          "},"otherParent":"NOAH LANDI-RODRIGUEZ","children":{"name":["BRAYDEN KACEVIC"]}}]}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/PaymentAdapter/payment/info/ncp".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[{"date":{"year":2015,"month":7,"day":8,"timezone"…3648,"minute":-2147483648,"second":-2147483648}}]", responseJSON: Array[6], invocationContext: null}
resp: klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[{"date":{"year":2015,"month":7,"day":8,"timezone"…3648,"minute":-2147483648,"second":-2147483648}}]", responseJSON: Array[6], invocationContext: null}
[MY.controllers.paymenthistory] payment info ncp on case change successful
resp: klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[{"date":{"year":2015,"month":7,"day":8,"timezone"…3648,"minute":-2147483648,"second":-2147483648}}]", responseJSON: Array[6], invocationContext: null}
Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.
toState=== Object {url: "/paymenthistory", views: Object, name: "app.paymenthistory"}
fromState=== Object {url: "/home", views: Object, name: "app.home"}
timeout elapsedTime :  5.733
timeout :  Stop
timeout : reStartSession 
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/PaymentAdapter/payment/info/cp".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[]", responseJSON: Array[0], invocationContext: null}
resp: klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[]", responseJSON: Array[0], invocationContext: null}invocationContext: nullresponseHeaders: ObjectresponseJSON: Array[0]responseText: "[]"status: 200__proto__: Object
[MY.controllers.paymenthistory] payment info cp on case change successful
Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/PaymentAdapter/payment/info/cp".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[]", responseJSON: Array[0], invocationContext: null}
resp: klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[]", responseJSON: Array[0], invocationContext: null}
[MY.controllers.paymenthistory] payment info cp on case change successful
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/PaymentAdapter/payment/info/ncp".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[{"date":{"year":2015,"month":7,"day":8,"timezone"…3648,"minute":-2147483648,"second":-2147483648}}]", responseJSON: Array[6], invocationContext: null}
resp: klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[{"date":{"year":2015,"month":7,"day":8,"timezone"…3648,"minute":-2147483648,"second":-2147483648}}]", responseJSON: Array[6], invocationContext: null}
[MY.controllers.paymenthistory] payment info ncp on case change successful
resp: klass {responseHeaders: Object, status: 200, responseText: "[{"date":{"year":2015,"month":7,"day":8,"timezone"…3648,"minute":-2147483648,"second":-2147483648}}]", responseJSON: Array[6], invocationContext: null}

[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
response [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat] success: 
Heartbeat sent successfully
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
response [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat] success: 
Heartbeat sent successfully
timeout elapsedTime :  600.004
Request [http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
XHR finished loading: GET "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=txi6uhiRuF&scope=-MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.6998167100291259".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
response [http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization] success: 
timeout : - Timeout occurred
[MY.timeoutFactory] timeout : WL.Client.logout.onSuccess():MYRealm: resp is {"responseHeaders":{"Date":"Tue, 26 Apr 2016 17:16:59 GMT","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Content-Length":"0","Content-Language":"en-US"},"status":200,"responseText":"","invocationContext":null,"response":{"request":{"options":{"method":"get","asynchronous":true,"contentType":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","encoding":"UTF-8","parameters":{"client_id":"txi6uhiRuF","scope":"-MYRealm","isAjaxRequest":"true","x":0.6998167100291259},"evalJSON":true,"evalJS":true,"timeout":30000,"onAuthentication":null,"isAuthResponse":null,"optionalHeaders":{"X-WL-Session":"a024e87e-4f12-1ec2-4d5c-d8a2b82fd896"},"requestHeaders":{"x-wl-app-version":"1.0","x-wl-app-details":"{\"applicationDetails\":{\"platformVersion\":\"7.1.0.0\",\"nativeVersion\":\"\"}}","WL-Instance-Id":"uu39jsbudjfiuttj6ohr2i7e1b","X-WL-Session":"a024e87e-4f12-1ec2-4d5c-d8a2b82fd896","X-WL-ClientId":"txi6uhiRuF","X-WL-S-ClientId":"txi6uhiRuF"}},"transport":{},"url":"http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=txi6uhiRuF&scope=-MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.6998167100291259","method":"get","parameters":{"client_id":"txi6uhiRuF","scope":"-MYRealm","isAjaxRequest":"true","x":"0.6998167100291259"},"trackingId":"3e3f7a4d-ad91-48b5-1c4d-475c77294c35","networkMetadata":{"$path":"http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?client_id=txi6uhiRuF&scope=-MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.6998167100291259","$category":"network","$trackingid":"3e3f7a4d-ad91-48b5-1c4d-475c77294c35","$outboundTimestamp":1461691020144,"$inboundTimestamp":1461691020350,"$bytesReceived":0,"$roundTripTime":206,"$responseCode":200},"body":null,"_complete":true},"transport":{},"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"OK","responseText":"","headerJSON":null,"responseXML":null,"responseJSON":null}}
GET http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/SecurityAdapter/security/login 401 (Unauthorized)
XHR finished loading: GET "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/SecurityAdapter/security/login".
Request [http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
GET http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/preview/MYMobileApp/common/1.0/default/icon%20ion-help 404 (Not Found)
GET http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/preview/MYMobileApp/common/1.0/default/icon%20ion-information 404 (Not Found)
XHR finished loading: GET "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/authorization/v1/authorization?response…2F%2Fmfpredirecturi&scope=MYRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.420548791173293".

[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
response [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat] success: 
Heartbeat sent successfully
Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.
JSONStore Find All returned : [{"_id":1,"json":{"userAgreementFlag":true}}]
Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.
toState=== Object {url: "/helpfulinformation", views: Object, name: "app.helpfulinformation"}
fromState=== Object {url: "/landing", views: Object, name: "app.landing"}
Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.
timeout elapsedTime :  1000.317
GET http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/LocationAdapter/office/list 401 (Unauthorized)
XHR finished loading: GET "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/LocationAdapter/office/list".
timeout elapsedTime :  1008.765
GET http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/LocationAdapter/office/list 401 (Unauthorized)
XHR finished loading: GET "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/adapters/LocationAdapter/office/list".
Request [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat]
Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}
XHR finished loading: POST "http://hostname:10080/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat".
[mfpAuth.helper.auth] _isCustomResponse():
klass {request: klass, transport: XMLHttpRequest, readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "OK"…}
response [/MyProject/apps/services/api/MYMobileApp/common/heartbeat] success: 
Heartbeat sent successfully
```

wlAuthenticator-module.js

https://www.dropbox.com/s/786t87fdotcllwk/wlAuthenticator-module.js?dl=0

Comment: Does any one know how can I get rid of this  401 (Unauthorized) issue

Comment: Make sure, double-check, triple-check, that every single time `handleChallenge` gets called that you always answer that challenge. A challenge unanswered will block the framework.
Also - did you fix the other issues by either using session-independence or sticky sessions?

Comment: Yes I have switched it to session Independent mode

Comment: That has fixed mt load blancer issue as well

Comment: What does this mean: 'handleChallenge(): Challenge Not Required'

Comment: That is coming from frm my wlAuthenticator-module.js  this._handleChallenge = function(response) {} method...if (authStatus == "complete"){
          logger.debug("_handleChallenge(): Challenge Not Required");
             theFactory.realmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
             theFactory.loginCompleteCallback();
             return false;
         }

Comment: "handleChallenge gets called that you always answer that challenge" Does this also applies for unprotected resourcess? Like we have adapters which should be accessed without logging in

Comment: I suggest you post the challenge handler source code in the question.

Comment: Yes. Always. I've added an answer because I think this is your issue. When using custom challenge handlers, the framework has no idea that a resource is unprotected. It is your responsibility to manage each challenge.

Comment: Your authentication seems overly complex. Why is there a single challenge handler that handles all kinds of different realms and challenges? So many ifs... It should not be like that.  I can't imagine debugging this code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `handleChallenge` is called, then the challenge **IS** required. You have to answer it, it's a requirement.

If a challenge is not required, it is the job of `isCustomResponse` to return `false`.

If `isCustomResponse` returned `true`, you are required to answer the challenge.

Comment: Nathan I think my issue is something else. For unprotected resource in my case isCustomResponse or handleChallenge is not invoked at all because the request it self did not made through.

Comment: We are using WLResourceRequest  object to send a request to any protected or unprotected resource

Comment: I was wandering when the App is first launched what type of authentication happens between Client and MFP? Does it have any expire?

Comment: Are you using any kind of gateway by any chance?

Comment: Gateway? I didn't catch that.

Comment: DataPower maybe? If you don't know what that is, you probably don't use one. At that point, I can only suggest that you open a PMR (support request) against IBM. Please provide them with a sample project that shows the unexpected behavior. Please make your sample as simple as possible for fastest results. Remove unnecessary dependencies from the sample such as angular if you can reproduce the bug without it.

Comment: Yes I did the same today, I created a new app and tried to reproduce the issue. But I was not able to reproduce.

Comment: Check this logs. What I found that after some time when token is expired and any new request is made worklight.js first gets the new token and then process the request.

Comment: This generation of new token is not happening in my app

Comment: I can't follow anymore. Please create a simple application demonstrating the issue and open a PMR.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Our isCustomResponse method was implemented incorrectly.

I have observed that once ChallengeHandler is implemented then all responses will go through isCustomResponse method if I am not wrong.

Normally WL object will generate the toke  when the first server is connected but after token is expired and if request is made, WL will get the new token and completes your request.  This process to get new token was effected by the third else if condition we had in or isCustomResponse method.

I compared my code with customLoginModule provided by MFP and found that extra condition does not make sense. Challenge Handler should be called only in scenario where response.responseJSON.authStatus is "required" or "completed" rest all the responses should just return as false by customResponse

```
  this._isCustomResponse = function(response) {
if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
                return false;
            }
 if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (response.responseJSON.authStatus) { 
                return true;
            }
            else if (response.responseJSON.MyRealm && response.responseJSON.MyRealm.isUserAuthenticated) {
                return true;
            }  
}
```

After removing the third else if - solved my issue.

```
this._isCustomResponse = function(response) {
     if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (response.responseJSON.authStatus) { 
                    return true;
                } 
    }
```